# ServiceRequestException: The request failed with Microsoft Exchange Server using Java

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

So I am trying to send a hello world email using the ews-java-api.

My code looks like:

```
    ExchangeService exchangeWebService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
    exchangeWebService.setCredentials(new WebCredentials(username , password, localPcDomain));
    exchangeWebService.setUrl(new URI(companyExchangeURL));
    EmailMessage msg= new EmailMessage(exchangeWebService);
    msg.setSubject("Hello world!");
    msg.setBody(MessageBody.getMessageBodyFromText("Sent using the EWS Java API."));
    msg.getToRecipients().add(testEmail);
    msg.send();
```

But I get the following exception:

```
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ServiceRequestException: The request failed. The request failed. sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Caused by: microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ServiceRequestException: The request failed. sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Any ideas on what I need to do? I have tried using autodiscover but it always seems to fail.

Answer (score 0):

From the error it sounds like it may be an SSL issue (invalid certificate, untrusted certificate, etc.). A quick test would be to go to the OWA url for that server and see if your browser gives a warning or error about the SSL cert.